# Show superscript value for UI-Grid cell header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have following scope variable and it has value `m3`.

How can i make 3 as superscript to m and show as display name to UI grid column header?

```
$scope.Unit = m3;
```

Comment: Superscript looks like this: `m<sup>3</sup>`. It's up to you to produce this markup however you want.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, thats the point i am asking for. How i can produce it directly inside controller? O

Answer (score 0):

In the controller -

```
$scope.trustedUnitHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('m<sup>3</sup>');
```

In the template -

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedUnitHtml"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting error "'$sce' is undefined" ! do i need to inject any service before i can use $sce?

Comment: Inject $sce into your controller.

Comment: I just updated my question because i need to use it in ui-grid as display name.